# running dataflow using docker-compose without swarm

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I launched spring-cloud dataflow using the following

```
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml \
               -f ./docker-compose-rabbitmq.yml \
               -f ./docker-compose-postgres.yml \
               -f ./docker-compose-influxdb.yml up
```

I created a stream like this

```
http --management.metrics.export.influx.uri=http://influxdb:8086 --spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.enabled=true --management.metrics.export.influx.db=myinfluxdb 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.auto-create-db=true | log 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.uri=http://influxdb:8086 --spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.enabled=true 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.db=myinfluxdb 
     --management.metrics.export.influx.auto-create-db=true
```

On my mac; I am able to monitor the streams but when I run on a Linux VM running RHEL; I keep getting 
"database not found: myinfluxdb" .. The configuration is identical. Anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: Can you confirm that a docker container `influxdb` is running? 
Also which DATAFLOW_VERSION and SKIPPER_VERSION are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing jumps out. You may want to hit the actuator endpoints of SCDF, Skipper, and apps; specifically, the `/configprops` to confirm whether the metrics properties are correctly bootstrapped and propagated over to the apps.

As well, it'd be nice to globally configure the InfluxDB properties in SCDF [see [global configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties)] instead of manually setting them up for each stream application. With this setup, Skipper when it deploys the apps, it will automatically pass them over on your behalf.

Comment: I actually copied the result of my stream creation and pasted; Sorry for misleading you. I believe the defaults are config from SCDF properties?

Comment: The /configprops endpoint matches whats in docker-compose.yml. I was hoping to adding    "logging.level.io.micrometer.influx":"DEBUG" to skipper/scdf to show anything but i dont see anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully tested using Ubuntu 19.10 and docker 19.03.2, docker-compose 1.21.0, e.g:

```
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfca03
docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
```

and using the docker-compose ymml files form master and:

```
export DATAFLOW_VERSION=2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
export SKIPPER_VERSION=2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```